# Search through an entire string

Tags: javascript, html

How would you search through an entire string and display each item found in a div?

The thing I'm searching for is a license code which starts with NVOS and ends with ". I'd like to extract the entire code except for the "

The thing I want to parse would be like NVOS-ABCD-EFG-HIJK-LM52P" but I don't want the " included.

Here is what I'm trying:

```
var myRe = /^NVOS[^"]*/g;
var myArray = myRe.exec(document.getElementById("txt").value);
console.log(myArray)
for (i in myArray){
console.log(i)
}
```

Not working.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you give an example of the string you are describing at very least?

Comment: var myRe = /Regexp here/;

var myArray = myRe.exec(document.getElementById("cd");

then use a for loop to print each item

Comment: Can you modify the question to provide the string, or a similar example to it that you want to parse?

Comment: modified the question

Comment: The initial `^` is an anchor that restricts matches to the start of the line, which probably isn't what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a regular expression.

```
var myString = document.body.innerHTML // substitute for your string
var regex = /NVOS[A-Z\-]+/g // /g (global) modifier searches for all matches

var matches = myString.match(regex);

for (var i=0; i<matches.length; i++)
  console.log( matches[i] )
  // NVOS-ABCD-EFG-HIJK-LM
  // NVOS-ABCD-EFG-HIJK-LM
```

Comment: Not what I wanted, it needs to return every code, not just one

Comment: @ECMA Not hard to modify it.

Comment: Edited the question to loop over all matches.

Answer (score 0):

lests say that your string is str.

//check if the code even have this characters  /x22 is for = " //

```
var newString  =  str.substr(str.indexOf("NVOS"),str.lastIndexOf("\x22") -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display each section in the console, then you could do it like this:

```
var licenseString = "NVOS-ABCD-EFG-HIJK-LM52P";
var stringSplit = licenseString.split("-");

for(var part in stringSplit) {
   console.log(stringSplit[part]);
}
```